# Using MIN function in excel when using mm:ss.00 fields and ignoring 00:00.00

Tags: excel, excel-2010

Does anyone know how I can get excel to look at the following fields, all formatted in mm:ss.00 and return the lowest time. I am using this to calculate PB's - personal best times - in a sports club race sheet.
The formula I am using is
=MIN(J5,(U5),(AE5),(AO5),(AY5),(BI5),(BS5),(CC5),(CM5),(CW5),(DG5),(DQ5),(EA5),(EK5),(EU5))
The problem I have at the moment is that it is including 00:00.00 values in the cells and returning a MIN value of 00:00.00.
Any suggestions would be welcomed.
many thanks
Nigel

Comment: Hi pnuts, I havent used the excel SMALL function before, I just tried it then and no it doesnt give me the outcome I need. It still returns 00:00.00 as the result. At least I now know about the SMALL function, thanks for the suggestion anyway. Nigel

Comment: Hi pnuts, thanks but I just tried what you suggested and I still get it returning 00:00.00 as the result. I dont know whats going on.It must be a format issue ?

Comment: strange, `small` works for me actually, unless there are more than one `00:00:00`

Comment: Sina's answer below using `countif` and `small` together should work for you

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
=SMALL((J5,U5,AE5,AO5,...),COUNTIF((J5,U5,AE5,AO5,...),0)+1)
```

`COUNTIF` counts the amounts of 0 (you maybe need to adjust this value based on your formatting, but it should work). `SMALL` returns the n-smallest number of the given matrix, with n being the counted value + 1.

Therefore if no 0 is in the matrix, you get the 1st-smallest (aka the smallest), with one 0 you get the 2nd-smallest and so on. Maybe you need to add a check if every value is 0, if that could happen, as in that case SMALL would try to retrieve the value on position list_size+1 of the list, which of course isn't present.